# What differencies between session.delete and delete using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

What differenicies between two variants:

1.

```
 session.createQuery("delete from Vacancy where id = :id")
                        .setInteger("id", vacancy.getId()).executeUpdate()
```

;

2
 . `session.delete(vacancy);`

Comment: Why don't you enable `show_sql` and check for yourself?

Comment: I noticed different behaviour in tests. in sql I see hgl script for hql

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using `session.delete` is that it cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with `cascade="delete"`.

But the cascade will not happen if you use the direct delete query using `createQuery`.

Comment: Is this actually the case? I'm pretty sure it isn't in JPQL (looking it up).

Comment: Hmm. "A delete operation only applies to entities of the specified class and its subclasses. It does not cascade to
related entities." I suppose this makes some sense from a performance perspective, but it's more than a bit unintuitive and seems like it could lead to inconsistent state (or at least FK errors).